# mule server Could not register server: Already paired

Tags: mule, mule-studio

This is my mule server http://17.156.435.270:8585/mmc-3.6.1/index.jsp

**I access server ip 17.156.435.270:8585 in my local machine**

1. ule Agent URL: **http://17.156.435.270:7777/mmc-support**
2. Server Name:    DevRetail

It shows

> Could not register server: Already paired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow MMC already thinks the server is registered. Probably becuase the truststore.jks is already there. Try deleting it from:

MULE_HOME/.mule/AGENT_NAME/truststore.jks

And restart and try re-registering.